# How to show only specific net in Diptrace?

Tags: pcb, routing

How to show only specific net in Diptrace?
Let's say i have a big board and i want to trace all the power traces first, i'd like to hide all other nets ratlines so it's easier to see just the power ratlines where it needs routing.
I don't want to hide all the other ones manualy one by one...
I see there's options to hide specific ratlines, or hide all the ratlines, but no option to show just one specific ratline nest at a time?
How do people usualy route specific nets at first without being overwhelmed by all the other nets and ratlines around it?

Comment: If you select View -> Ratlines -> routed net only  Then once you start drawing a trace it will hide the ratlines of the other traces.

Comment: yeah i noticed that but the goal is to see what else needs to be routed in the power net, it's not very convenient to have to search for the next component to route to see which one needs routing.

Comment: found a work around... i put a different color for the power nets...